# What is the remainder when $ n^n $ is divided by $ (n-1) $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to find out the remainder if $ n^n $ is divided by $(n-1)$ . I have tried investigating a number of examples for small $n$:

- $ 2^2 $ is divided by $1$ gives remainder $0 $
- $ 3^3 $ is divided by $2$ gives remainder $1$
- $ 4^4 $ is divided by $3$ gives remainder $1$
- $ 5^5 $ is divided by $4$ gives remainder $1$
- $ 6^6 $ is divided by $5$ gives remainder $1$

But I can't identify any pattern to find out the remainder. So please help me to find out the remainder if $ n^n $ is divided by $ n-1 $.

Comment: $4^4$ divided by $3$ gives $1$. The answer is always $1$

Comment: That is a huge mistake . Many many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers are all correct. But since you posted such an elementary problem, I guess it would be better if you learnt how to attack this problem rather than only the solution of it.

See, you need to find out $n^n \pmod{n-1}$ where $n>2$. Whenever you need to find mod of such products, the first thing to try is finding out the mod of individual terms (the others being some manipulation or Euler's/Fermat's little theorem if it's a power etc.). Now, in this case, it is evident that $n \equiv (n-1)+1 \equiv 1 \pmod{n-1}$.

We know that, taking mod is multiplicative. So, $n^n \equiv (1)^n \pmod{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n-1}$.

Please comment if you need further clarifications.

Comment: I think it would have better if you used \equiv $\equiv$ instead of =

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan You're right. Edited.

Answer (score 7):

$$n^n \equiv ((n-1)+1)^n \equiv 1^n \equiv 1 \pmod {n-1}$$

Comment: It would probably more helpful to the OP if you edited in where this equation comes from. (I understand it, but OP need not necessarily do so, it's mostly just an equation completely out of context. >_>)

Comment: I cant understand your solution . Can you please make elaboration of this solution ?

Comment: @StandardEquation Do you know modular arithmetic / congruences?  It helps to add such context to your questions.  You accepted an answer using modular arithmetic, so how could you understand that but not this? (they are equivalent)

Answer (score 7):

$n^n = (n^{n-1} + n^{n-2} +\ldots + 1)(n-1) + 1$. Its a telescope sum.

Comment: It would probably more helpful to the OP if you edited in where this equation comes from. (I understand it, but OP need not necessarily do so, it's mostly just an equation completely out of context. >_>)

Comment: This solution make sense to me . Many many thanks

Answer (score 4):

For n>2:

Binomial expansion:

$(1+(n-1))^n=$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(n-1)^k+1;$

The first term is divisible by $(n-1)$, the remainder is $1$.

Comment: Except when $\,|n-1| = 1\,$ when the remainder $\,r= 0\neq 1,\,$ but $\,0\equiv 1\pmod{\!\pm\!1},\,$ i.e. $\, r\equiv 1\pmod{n\!-\!1}\ $ is always true.

Comment: Bill.Oops. Thanks for your comment. n>2. Shall fix it.